# base64 image can't save in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cors, base64

I use angular for sending differents data in my nodejs backend and save them in mongodb.
My problem is when I save base64 image. When the base64 is short, (30kB) it's good but when I try to save higher image (100 kB) I have this error :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/cdirectories/' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource :

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),
    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
        );
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
```

I have tried to convert this image on Blob but impossible to find how add type: Blob in mongodb :

```
const cdirectorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    cdirectoryId: {type: String},
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english

Comment: Are you sure you want to save images in mongodb? In general it is not a good idea. You could save it to a file storage like aws s3 or azure blob storage and save the url to mongo

Comment: Yes i know it's not good idea, it's temporary. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `body-parser`? If so, check the `limit` option, it sets the maximum request body size, default value is 100kb, you can set it to a larger number, like '10mb'